# Python Indentation (for loop)

Tags: python, python-2.7, indentation

Can anyone help me with the following before it drives me insane :)

```
`for row in reader:
if headers:
conn.execute('INSERT INTO COMPANY (Brand, Stock_Code, Description, Quantity,        Price_Ex_VAT) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);', (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]))
y = y + 1
if x == 0:
        stdout.write("\rWorking \\")
#print("Working.", end = "")
   elif x == 1:
   stdout.write("\rWorking |")
   #print("Working..", end="")
   elif x == 2:
   stdout.write("\rWorking /")
   #print("Working..", end="")
   else:
   stdout.write("\rWorking -")
   x = -1
   #print("Working", end = "")
   stdout.flush()
   x = x +1
   else:
   headers = True 
   stdout.write("\n") # move the cursor to the next line
   stdout.write("Complete ")
   stdout.write(str(y))`
```

Ive been messing with this now for about 3 hours to no avail.  Thanks guys

Comment: Help how? What is the problem?

Comment: im just getting an indentation error that i cant seem to fix :(

Comment: You have to indent after `elif` or `else`

Comment: It's because the code under your ifs/elifs/elses have to be indented as per python standards. We can't fix it without knowing the logic behind all of the conditionals.

Comment: Additionally Some editors don't like tabs. Use 4 Spaces instead of tabs. This is assuming you know how the logic of your code works.

Comment: The problem is because Python uses whitespace to indicate loops and whatnot, if you don't have the proper whitespace it's almost impossible for us to know exactly what you're trying to do. Bit of a catch-22.

Comment: @user3450524 your code is formatted incorrectly in many ways.  Please fix the snippet so it appears *exactly* as you are seeing it in your local editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
for row in reader:
    if headers:
        conn.execute('INSERT INTO COMPANY (Brand, Stock_Code, Description, Quantity, Price_Ex_VAT) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);', (row[0],    row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]))
        y = y + 1
        if x == 0:
            stdout.write("\rWorking \\")
            #print("Working.", end = "")
        elif x == 1:
            stdout.write("\rWorking |")
            #print("Working..", end="")
        elif x == 2:
            stdout.write("\rWorking /")
            #print("Working..", end="")
        else:
            stdout.write("\rWorking -")
            x = -1
            #print("Working", end = "")
        stdout.flush()
        x = x +1
    else:
        headers = True
        stdout.write("\n") # move the cursor to the next line
    stdout.write("Complete ")
    stdout.write(str(y))
```

Wasn't sure about the indentions on the last 3 stdouts, but that should work. But you're still going to have problems if you're intermingling tabs and spaces. I don't know what editor you're using, but you should expand the tabs to spaces.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone else has pointed out, in Python, indentation is meaningful. Code blocks should be indented. For example, an `if` loop should be indented like this:

[pseudocode]

```
if condition:
    performAction
elif otherCondition:
    performOtherAction
else:
    performDefaultAction
```

I've tried to reformat your code as I think it is supposed to be indented. Comment whether you think this is what it SHOULD look like.

```
for row in reader:
    if headers:
        conn.execute('INSERT INTO COMPANY (Brand, Stock_Code, Description, Quantity, Price_Ex_VAT) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);', (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]))
        y = y + 1
        if x == 0:
            stdout.write("\rWorking \\")
            #print("Working.", end = "")
       elif x == 1:
           stdout.write("\rWorking |")
           #print("Working..", end="")
       elif x == 2:
           stdout.write("\rWorking /")
           #print("Working..", end="")
       else:
           stdout.write("\rWorking -")
           x = -1
          #print("Working", end = "")
          stdout.flush()
       x = x +1
   else:
       headers = True 
       stdout.write("\n") # move the cursor to the next line
       stdout.write("Complete ")
   stdout.write(str(y)) #assuming that you are writing out the value of y regardless of value of headers
```

Comment: Its good and all to give him the answer, but it would be nice to explain to him why the problem happened.

Comment: I'll clarify what I'm doing here.